# How to show deleted file when using command `find . -name sample.txt -delete`

Tags: find, verbose

I need the output just like `rm -v sample.txt`.
Are there options like "-v" in command find？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested with FreeBSD and Busybox implementations of `find`:

```
$ find . -name sample.txt  -delete -exec echo removed "'{}'" \; | sed "s,^removed '\./,removed ',"
removed 'sample.txt'
```

With GNU find you can also use `-printf`:

```
$ find . -name sample.txt -printf "removed '%f'\n" -delete
removed 'sample.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple stupid solution:

```
find . -name sample.txt && find . -name sample.txt -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
find . -name sample.txt | xargs rm -vf
```